# Why do I need to include libraries used in other libraries?

Tags: library, c++, build

I have a simple library which uses another library.

Here is the header:

```
#ifndef __DERIVEDCLASS_H__
#define __DERIVEDCLASS_H__

#include <HardwareSerial.h>

class DerivedClass
{
private:
    HardwareSerial* serial;

public:
    DerivedClass();
};
#endif
```

And the CPP:

```
#include "DerivedClass.h"

DerivedClass::DerivedClass()
{

}
```

And the sketch:

```
#include <DerivedClass.h>

void setup()
{
}

void loop()
{
}
```

This works fine.

However, if I change the library header to this:

```
#ifndef __DERIVEDCLASS_H__
#define __DERIVEDCLASS_H__

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

class DerivedClass
{
private:
    SoftwareSerial* serial;

public:
    DerivedClass();
};
#endif
```

The sketch fails to compile:

> /Users/andrew/Documents/Arduino/libraries/DerivedClass/DerivedClass.h:9:
>   error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'SoftwareSerial' with no type
>   /Users/andrew/Documents/Arduino/libraries/DerivedClass/DerivedClass.h:9:
>   error: expected ';' before '*' token

If I change the sketch to:

```
#include <DerivedClass.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

void setup()
{
}

void loop()
{
}
```

i.e. including the SoftwareSerial library in the top level sketch, it compiles fine.

If I expand the library out so it actually performs actions, then if it compiles, it works.

Why is this? HardwareSerial is a built-in part of the Arduino, located in *hardware/arduino/cores/arduino* and SoftwareSerial is in *libraries*, but why would the build process differentiate between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly this is in fact a limitation of the **Arduino IDE**.

If you use a better IDE (personally I use Eclipse with the Arduino plugin) it works as it should, i.e. if you include a library A that includes another library B, then in the end you won't get compile-time errors and both B and A will be included in the final binary.

Comment: Absolutely right. Just tried Stino and it works fine. I might retreat back to using command line. I can't understand why they would do this.

Comment: Indeed, they are trying to fix this in 1.5 https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/pull/1726