# Include statement not working

Tags: c++, library

I am creating my own library for the Arduino and I have the following code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Servo.h>

class ServoMotorController {
    public:
        ServoMotorController(int servoPin, int motorPin, int angle);
        void setAngle(int angle);
        void setSpeed(int speed);
    private:
        Servo servo;

        int servoPin;
        int servoAngle;
        int motorPin;
        int motorSpeed;
};
```

I am getting the error that `Servo` does not name a type; however if I do

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include <ServoMotorController.h>
```

in my actual Arduino code then I do not get the error. **Why is the include statement not working in my C++ lib?**

Comment: Where are the files located?  There is an important distinction between `#include <File.h>` and `#include "File.h"`.

Comment: There is a folder called "libraries" in them there are (for our purposes) 2 folders "ServoMotorController" (which has my files) and "Servo" (which has the servo files)

Comment: Check out the include path that is configured for your pre-processor/compiler.  It is quite possible the folders aren't included.

Comment: Here is the thing.  When I do include "" it says the file deosn't exist.  But when I do include <> no such error occurs.  Ontop of that the file is actually called SoftwareServo.h but the arduino software just include Servo.h...

Comment: It seems this question is similar to http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/322/why-do-i-need-to-include-libraries-used-in-other-libraries I suggest you take a look at it, it may provide you with the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is a symptom of the arduino IDE. libraries can't add other libraries to the include path, but the can use other libs if they have already been included. you can use an error directive so your compiler output is more informative at least

```
#ifndef Servo_h
    #error "ServoMotorController Lib requires Servo.h to be included first to function"
#else
```

Arduino 1.5.6 beta's new library format has a section for dependencies in the new library.properties file that should allow one library to add another to the include path, but I'm not entirely sure if the functionality is fully implemented yet (its beta after all).